# Ubuntu DNS resolver not use DNS Over TLS port 853 for DNS resolve

Tags: networking, dns, systemd-resolved

I have Ubuntu 20.04 server. This server is set up to run WordPress sites (*LEMP stack*). In this server, I have set up an ubuntu DNS resolver to use "DNS Over TLS". Use Cloudflare DNS service.

When I run the following commands I can see that it use port 53, not use DNS Over TLS port 853. In my CSF firewall, I have allowed port 853 in TPC and UDP (in/out).

What could be the reason for this? How do I force ubuntu to use DNSOverTLS?

**resolved.conf configurations.**

```
[Resolve]
DNS=1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1 2606:4700:4700::1111 2606:4700:4700::1001
#FallbackDNS=
#Domains=
#LLMNR=no
#MulticastDNS=no
DNSSEC=yes
DNSOverTLS=yes
Cache=no-negative
#DNSStubListener=yes
#ReadEtcHosts=yes
```

These are my testing results.

```
root@server:~# nslookup google.com
Server:         1.1.1.1
Address:        1.1.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 142.250.65.174
Name:   google.com
Address: 2607:f8b0:4006:81e::200e


root@server:~# kdig -d google.com
;; DEBUG: Querying for owner(google.com.), class(1), type(1), server(1.1.1.1), port(53), protocol(UDP)
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY; status: NOERROR; id: 51182
;; Flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1; ANSWER: 1; AUTHORITY: 0; ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;; google.com.                  IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.             246     IN      A       142.251.40.142

;; Received 44 B
;; Time 2022-01-30 16:17:34 +0530
;; From 1.1.1.1@53(UDP) in 1.3 ms
```

However, when I run the following command, it uses DNS over TLS (port 853).

```
root@server:~# kdig -d @1.1.1.1 +tls-ca +tls-host=cloudflare-dns.com  example.com
;; DEBUG: Querying for owner(example.com.), class(1), type(1), server(1.1.1.1), port(853), protocol(TCP)
;; DEBUG: TLS, imported 128 system certificates
;; DEBUG: TLS, received certificate hierarchy:
;; DEBUG:  #1, C=US,ST=California,L=San Francisco,O=Cloudflare\, Inc.,CN=cloudflare-dns.com
;; DEBUG:      SHA-256 PIN: RKlx+/Jwn2A+dVoU8gQWeRN2+2JxXcFkAczKfgU8OAI=
;; DEBUG:  #2, C=US,O=DigiCert Inc,CN=DigiCert TLS Hybrid ECC SHA384 2020 CA1
;; DEBUG:      SHA-256 PIN: e0IRz5Tio3GA1Xs4fUVWmH1xHDiH2dMbVtCBSkOIdqM=
;; DEBUG: TLS, skipping certificate PIN check
;; DEBUG: TLS, The certificate is trusted.
;; TLS session (TLS1.3)-(ECDHE-X25519)-(ECDSA-SECP256R1-SHA256)-(AES-256-GCM)
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY; status: NOERROR; id: 16525
;; Flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1; ANSWER: 1; AUTHORITY: 0; ADDITIONAL: 1

;; EDNS PSEUDOSECTION:
;; Version: 0; flags: ; UDP size: 1232 B; ext-rcode: NOERROR
;; PADDING: 408 B

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;; example.com.                 IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.            68347   IN      A       93.184.216.34

;; Received 468 B
;; Time 2022-01-30 16:02:33 +0530
;; From 1.1.1.1@853(TCP) in 1.7 ms
```

When I check the resolver status, it shows DNS over TLS enabled.

```
root@server:~# systemd-resolve --status
Global
       LLMNR setting: no
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: yes
      DNSSEC setting: yes
    DNSSEC supported: yes
         DNS Servers: 1.1.1.1
                      1.0.0.1
                      2606:4700:4700::1111
                      2606:4700:4700::1001
                      94.237.127.9
                      94.237.40.9
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 4 (eth2)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: yes
      DNSSEC setting: yes
    DNSSEC supported: yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I am on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, the following solution worked for me, but with one extra step:

https://andrea.corbellini.name/2020/04/28/ubuntu-global-dns/#step-2-disable-dns-processing-in-networkmanager

In case the link goes dead, the relevant part is included in my answer. You need to create a file in `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/` in this example named `dns.conf` with the following content:

```
[main]
dns=none
systemd-resolved=false
```

This disallows NetworkManager to override the content of `/etc/resolved.conf`

Now, the extra step is that you need to edit `/etc/resolved.conf` to use the local dns resolved provided by systemd-resolved. But be careful, as it might be linked to some other file, so first unlink it, before you make any unintended changes. The only line it needs to contain is this:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

Additionally I changed its permissions to 555 using chmod to avoid any other program overwriting it.

Tests using Wireshark show that all dns queries are transferred using TLS on port 853.